# How can I enforce scale out limit in an ARM template for a premium function app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

[image: scaleout]

How to change Plan Scale out to 5 and App Scale out to 5 using ARM template

Comment: Have you tried setting the limit and then going to https://resources.azure.com to see how it looks?

Comment: i tried after changing the settings going to resources.azure.com i can see under site settings functionAppScaleLimit:5

Comment: i tried
`{
     "name": "functionAppScaleLimit",
     "value": "5" 
                        },
az functionapp plan update -g $(resourceGroup) -n premiumplanname --max-burst 5

az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g $(resourceGroup) -n functionappname/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=4
`
nothing is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about premium functions though but this works for normal serverless functions.

```json
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appPlanName'))]",
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "siteConfig": {
          "ftpsState": "Disabled",
          "functionAppScaleLimit": 2,
          "appSettings": [ ... ]
        }
      }
}
```

I guess you need the following site properties for the other settings:

```json
"preWarmedInstanceCount": null,
"minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0,
```